# Exoskeletons and rabid baboons

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am trying to remember the name of a book. I assume it was SciFi because I remember the crew in the story used exoskeletons to assist in their manual labour. I think they were on a planet marooned or not but in a jungle environment . The only other story point I remember was that they were attacked by vicious baboon like creatures.

Comment: Any chance that this would be the same story as referred to by this recent question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186177/man-on-another-world-kicked-out-of-colony-tries-to-survive-in-jungle ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like one of Edmund Cooper's Expendables series - the four novels in the series were about a team of astronauts led by James Conrad, proving planets safe for colonisation. Standard equipment included large exoskeletons, and the team members are all felons and hence considered Expendable.

In one of the novels, The Venom of Argus, the explorers encounter a tribe of baboon-like creatures which, while initially friendly, later attack and kill one of the team. It transpires they have been affected by the pollen from a plant with LSD-like properties, which also affects the male members of the exploratory team.

The series consists of four books - The Deathworms of Kratos, The Rings of Tantalus, The Wargames of Zelos, and The Venom of Argus.